Триггер ввода команды в JavaScript-консоль?
Я хочу настроить функцию, вызываемую, когда пользователь пытается выполнить любой код в JS-консоли (F12 -> Console) на моём сайте. И, в идеале, прервать эту попытку. Какие инструменты существуют (если существуют) для реализации этой затеи на чистом JavaScript?

Никакие. Вы не можете запретить пользователя открывать консоль и сделать там что-то

Максимум что вы можете делать, и то не зашита на 100%, это использовать модули, которые инкапсулируют код, так же не использовать никакие глобальные переменные (подключенные к Window). В таком раскладе у пользователя не будет доступ к вашим функционалам, но изменить локальные данные у себя он все же сможет.

Можно отслеживать событие открытия devtools по изменению размера окна https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect#caveats - обратите внимание на особенности: метод не дает гарантий верных срабатываний.
